# Unable to append input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have an add `button`,on click of that an `input` field must be appended.Instead of `input`,if I place `<p>` in `append()`,it is appending.Where I am going wrong ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="inputstack">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" id="addinput" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.selector').on('blur',function () {
    var current_value = $(this).val();
  $(this).attr('value',current_value);
console.log(current_value);
    if ($('.selector[value="' + current_value + '"]').not($(this)).length > 0 || current_value.length == 0 ) {
      $(this).focus();
        alert('You cannot use this');
    }
});
$('#addinput').click(function(){
$('#inputstack').append("<input type="text" class="selector" value="">");
});
```

My [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/0c0qep6y/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax error .. please keep eye on console .. quotes problem

```
$('#inputstack').append('<input type="text" class="selector" value="">');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0c0qep6y/19/)

Comment: @IamRaviteja never mind its always happening when you spend more time in coding .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the double quotes to single quotes like this:

```
$('#addinput').click(function(){
  $('#inputstack').append('<input type="text" class="selector" value="">');
});
```